# I can't seem to figure out quick.db

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

So I'm trying to make a marry command with discord.js-commando and quick.db, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. Even if the id exists in the database, it still returns code that is called if it doesn't exist. Here is my code, any help is appreciated!

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const db = require("quick.db");


module.exports = class MarryCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'marry',
      memberName: 'marry',
      group: 'guild',
      description: 'Marry the mentioned user',
      guildOnly: true,
      args: [
        {
          key: 'userToMarry',
          prompt: 'Please mention the member that you want to marry.',
          type: 'member'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  run(message, { userToMarry }) {
    const member = userToMarry;
    const exists = db.get(message.author.id);
    const married = db.get(userToMarry.id);
    if (!member) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: Please try again with a valid user.')}
    if (exists == message.author.id || married == message.author.id) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: You already married!')}
    if (exists == userToMarry.id || married == userToMarry.id) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: This user is already married!')}
    if (exists != message.author.id && exists != userToMarry.id && married != userToMarry.id && married != message.author.id) {
    message.channel.send(`:heart: ${userToMarry}, do you want marry ${message.author}?`);
      message.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id == userToMarry.id, {max: 1}).then(collected => {
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'no') {
      return message.channel.send(':x: Looks like a **no** to me...')}
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
      db.set(message.author.id, { partner: userToMarry.id });
      db.set(userToMarry.id, { partner: message.author.id });
    message.channel.send(`:heart: ${message.author} and ${userToMarry} are now married!`)
      .catch(err => {
        message.channel.send(
          `:x: Something went wrong when trying to marry this user.`
        );
        return console.log(err)});
      }
  });
}}};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question tittle to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results looking for a solution to their problem. Your current title has no value for that purpose, and provides no information that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I was not adding a value to the key, so in the end I got this: (added other things too)

```js
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const db = require("quick.db");


module.exports = class MarryCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'marry',
      memberName: 'marry',
      group: 'other',
      description: 'Marry the mentioned user',
      guildOnly: true,
      args: [
        {
          key: 'userToMarry',
          prompt: 'Please mention the member that you want to marry.',
          type: 'member'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  run(message, { userToMarry }) {
    const exists = db.get(`${message.author.id}.user`);
    const married = db.get(`${userToMarry.id}.user`);
    if (!userToMarry) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: Please try again with a valid user.')}
    if (exists == message.author.id) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: You are already married!')}
    if (married == userToMarry.id) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: This user is already married!')}
    if (userToMarry.id == message.author.id) {
      return message.channel.send(':x: You can\'t marry yourself!');
    }
    if (exists != message.author.id && married != userToMarry.id) {
    message.channel.send(`:heart: ${userToMarry}, do you want marry ${message.author}?`);
      message.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id == userToMarry.id, {max: 1}).then(collected => {
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'no') {
      return message.channel.send(':x: Looks like a **no** to me...')}
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
      db.set(message.author.id, { user: message.author.id, partner: userToMarry.id });
      db.set(userToMarry.id, { user: userToMarry.id, partner: message.author.id });
    message.channel.send(`:heart: ${message.author} and ${userToMarry} are now married!`)
      .catch(err => {
        message.channel.send(
          `:x: Something went wrong when trying to marry this user. ${err}`
        );
        return console.log(err)});
      }
  });
}}};
```